# How to produce range with step in Perl

Tags: perl

In Bash, `seq 5 5 20` produces `5 10 15 20`.

In Perl, `1..5` produces `1 2 3 4 5`; does it support step?

How do I produce a range with step in Perl?

Answer (score 36):

[perldoc -f map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is one way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @ns = map { 5 * $_ } 1 .. 4;
print Dumper(\@ns);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          5,
          10,
          15,
          20
        ];
```

See also: [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

Comment: Map is always very cool. The problem is that `map` is harder to read than a simple `for` as suggested by [eugene y](http://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-y), and is actually more inefficient and possibly slower. This has to generate the entire list. Imagine a loop like this `foreach my $i (map 5 * $_, 1..5000000) {`. You have to generate that 1,000,000 member list before you can do the loop. However, `for (my $i = 5; $i <= 5000000; $i += 5) {` doesn't have to generate a list first before executing.

Comment: @DavidW. : Nor does `List::Gen`'s `range` function

Comment: @DavidW. I think that `for` loops also generate the list beforehand. It looks like it does not, but `for` does use a list context for its arguments. A `while` loop does not, however.

Comment: @TLP - There are two separate `for` loop formats. The Bourne shell style (which I'll call the `foreach` loop) and the C style (which I'll call the `for` loop). The `foreach` variant does generate a list first, but not the `for variant. Yes, I know that `foreach` and `for` are interchangeable as keywords. The point is that the loop Eugene Y used in his example doesn't generate a list first.

Comment: @Zaid - Never seen List::Gen before. I'll have to play with it.

Comment: @DavidW. => if the argument to a `foreach` loop is a range operator, then it remains lazy (at least in modern versions of perl).  In this case, you could move the transform inside `for (1 .. 5e6) {my $i = $_ * 5; ...}` if you had to loop over such a large range.

Comment: @DavidW. Are you sure? Can you provide documentation or example that shows that c-style for loops do not generate the list beforehand?

Comment: @TLP => there is no list in the arguments of the c-style `for` loop: `for (void; boolean; void) {void}`.  there is of course list context in the foreach loop, but I like to call that iterative context, due to the optimizations that perl performs (a single range operator or array dereference will be iterated over rather than expanded in list context and then consumed (as would happen with a subroutine call))

Comment: @EricStrom Whether a list is iterated over or consumed, it still does exist in memory. I've been told before that even c-style for loops do create a list, i.e. that `for ($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)`, `for $i (0..$x)` and `for (0,1,2,3,4,5...$x)` all create this argument list beforehand. Are you saying this is not the case?

Comment: @TLP => Not at all. The `for (;;)` loop never builds any sort of list, it is actually just a fancy `while` loop.  You can prove it to yourself by changing the increment to `say $i++` and using last to exit the loop early. The `for (0..$x)` loop wont build a list either, but only because the `foreach` loop is magical and detects the range operator and optimizes it. If the `foreach` loop has anything except a simple range or array dereference, then and only then will a list be created of the elements. So only the last case uses memory to construct the list.  Whoever told you otherwise was wrong.

Answer (score 29):

The range operator in Perl doesn't support steps. You could use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (my $i = 5; $i <= 20; $i += 5) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: +1: This is a much better solution than `map`. I use to write in [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) and the joke was is that APL is a _Write-Only_ language because the code was always impossible to read. Map is neat, but it can have that _Write Only_ quality to it. Looking at the `for` loop, and I immediately see what my loop does. I can see it starts at 5. I can see it goes to 20. And, I can see it takes steps of 5. With `map`, I have to decode it first in order to understand it.

Comment: as written this is of course fine, but it is worth noting that if floats are used in the range, then you can run into compound floating point errors as the range gets longer.

Comment: The perl range operator operator creates an array.  This for loop does not.  So, I don't think it addresses the question.

Comment: @malcook: 1) the range operator returns a list, not an array. 2) what is stopping you from pushing the value to an array?

Comment: @eugeney  1) ah - yes - list, not array - good and thanks. 2) it is not me per se, but my (perhaps mis-) understanding of the original poster request to have the semantics of the range operatorl not a looping construct.

Answer (score 24):

The [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Gen) `range` function does this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Gen;

my $range = range 5, 20, 5;

say for @$range;      # 5
                      # 10
                      # 15
                      # 20

say while <$range>;   # TIMT1WTDI
$range->say;          # TAMT2WTDI, v.0.974
say $range->str;      # TAMT3WTDI, v.0.974

my $by_fives = <5 .. 20 by 5>;

say while <$by_fives>;     #TAMT4WTDI
<5 .. * by 5>->say( 4 );   #TAMT5WTDI
```

Comment: +1 I knew there must be a module for this, but I couldn't find it. Good work.

Comment: when `glob` is imported (as with a bare `use List::Gen;`) then you can write it as `<5 .. 20 by 5>`, `<5 .. 20 += 5>`, or even `<5..20+5>` if you are golfing.  I find these all a bit more expressive than the three argument `range`, but I guess you could also write `range 5 => 20, +5` to annotate the arguments.  It is also useful to note that `range` is fully lazy (elements calculated on demand) so you can write an infinite range `<5 .. * by 5>` and then take any slices of the range that you need.

Comment: @EricStrom : Great module! I'm trying to capture the ways you've mentioned in my answer. Why does `say while < 5 .. 20 by 5 >;` go into an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad people are finding it useful.  The problem is angle brackets do two different things.  When perl sees `<bareword>` or `<$simple_scalar>` it reads it as `readline ...` but when perl sees anything more complex than that between the brackets, the `glob` function is called.  so `say while <5..20+5>` gets read as `say while glob '5..20+5'` rather than `say while readline(glob('5..20+5'))`.  An since glob is not special in a while loop, nothing useful happens. Basically it is just a syntax issue, and putting the generator into a scalar fixes things as you have found.

Comment: wow ... didn't know about this.  By its docs it looks really interesting and useful!  Thank you

Comment: @zdim the credit really belongs to Eric. He used to be reasonably active a few years back, when users were a lot more welcoming to newcomers and the environment wasn't nearly as acrid.

Comment: Thanks for saying that ... I've noticed positions and manners that are really ... disorienting for me.  I started being active here less than a year ago but have used the site a lot all along -- and I thought that it had been different.  It's a little confusing, as to how exactly to behave.  It seems that friendly and nice doesn't cut it and that atmosphere is hard for me.

Comment: Alas, List::Gen is no longer supported, and doesn't compile any more.

Answer (score 8):

Not as good as [toolic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820169/how-to-produce-range-with-step-in-perl/8820255#8820255):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ns;

for my $n (1..4) {
    push(@ns, $n*5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [`Acme::Range::Module`](https://metacpan.org/module/Acme%3a%3aGlobule%3a%3aRange) a while back as a gag module - hence the `Acme::` namespace - but it does do what you want and has tests and is supported. Here's the example code:

```
use Acme::Globule qw( Range );

foreach (<10..1>) {
  print "$_... ";
}
print "Lift-off!\n";

# put down that crack pipe...
sub my_keys(\%) {
  my @hash = %{ $_[0] };
 return @hash[ glob("0,2..$#hash") ];
}

sub my_values(\%) {
  my @hash = %{ $_[0] };
 return @hash[ glob("1,3..$#hash") ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy solution that utilizes map and the built-in range operator:

```
sub range {
    my ($start, $end, $step) = @_; 
    $step ||= 1;
    return map { $_ * $step } ($start / $step .. $end / $step);
}
```

Notice the key point here is the map {} block. We simply divide the end
by the given step (works for negative and positive) then map each value
to the multiple of the given step.

Comment: The start, end, and step values I tried produced unexpected results: `print join(':', range(-0.3, -0.1, 0.1));` produces `-0.2:-0.1` due to numerical inaccuracies. :-D. -0.4 - -0,1 is fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Like the map solution :)

Here it is used to look for files starting with even numbers in a range 116 to 648:

```
perl -e 'foreach  (map { 2 * $_ } (116/2) .. (648/2)) { system("ls -l $_*"); } '
```

Perl is just wonderful for some jobs and making funny one-liners :)